# Transição em elementos usando :hover:after

Tags: css, seletores, css-transições

Como posso aplicar uma transição, por exemplo em um `background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%)` sem `hover` e `background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%)` com `hover` no after de um elemento ?

Por exemplo, tentei o seguinte código:

```
a:after{
   content:'';
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   position:absolute;
   background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%);
   transition:background 1s ease-out
}
a:hover:after{
   background:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%)
}
```

mas aparentemente não funcionou, existe alguma forma de realizar isso ?

Comment: Está a funcionar este seu código.


https://jsfiddle.net/vqub032t/

Comment: mas e a transição ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradientes não suportam transições ainda (embora a especificação diz que eles deveriam).

> ## transição gradiente CSS3 com background-position
>
> Embora você não pode animar directamente gradientes usando a propriedade de transição CSS, é possível animar a propriedade background-position para alcançar uma animação simples gradiente:

O código para isso é simples:

```css
#DemoGradient{  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
    background: linear-gradient(#C7D3DC,#5B798E);  
  
    -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;  
    transition: background 1s ease-out;  
  
    background-size:1px 200px;  
    border-radius: 10px;  
    border: 1px solid #839DB0;  
    cursor:pointer;  
    width: 150px;  
    height: 100px;  
}  
#DemoGradient:Hover{  
    background-position:100px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="DemoGradient"></div>
```

Ou usar a transição da opacidade:

```css
a:after{
   content:'';
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   position:absolute;
   background:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
   transition: all 1s;
  opacity: .7;
}
a:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;   
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```